# ActiveAdmin: Open show page in Facebox

Tags: customization, activeadmin

As the title suggests, I am trying to get the view link on the index page for my resource to open the show page in a facebox or other popup window, without the main page redirecting and loading the page there. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the view link with your own link logic.

```
index do
  selectable_column
  column :name
  actions do |resource|
    link_to "View", resource.facebook_url
  end
end
```

CITE: http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html